# Bootstrap multiple Modal components to pop up as page loads

Tags: javascript

```
let myOtherModal = new bootstrap.Modal(
  document.getElementById("signUpModal"),
  {}
);
myOtherModal.show();
let myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("myModal"), {});
myModal.show();
```

I have the above code on the js file linked to the layout page. It works out with the first modal, that correctly pops up when the page is loaded, but does not work with the second one. It doesn't work also when I move myOtherModal.show() to after the myModal variable declaration...
Why does order matters here and how can I make all modals work?

HMTL code - view "profile"

```
    <div
  class="modal fade"
  id="myModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign Up</h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="/login" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" />
          <br />
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" />
          <br />
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" />
          <br />
          <label for="passwordCheck">Confirm password</label>
          <input type="password" name="passwordCheck" />
          <br>
          <label for="imageUrl">Profile Picture</label>
          <input type="file" name="imageUrl">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-secondary"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
        >Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#logInModal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Log In</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

HTML code - view "index"

```
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="signUpModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="signUpModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="signUpModalLabel">Sign Up</h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="/signup" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" />
          <br />
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" />
          <br />
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" />
          <br />
          <label for="passwordCheck">Confirm password</label>
          <input type="password" name="passwordCheck" />
          <br>
          <label for="imageUrl">Profile Picture</label>
          <input type="file" name="imageUrl">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-secondary"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
        >Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#logInModal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are "signUpModal" and "myModal"?

Comment: The 2 modals I have defined in the app. I want both of them to automatically show on page load. One of them is in one view and the other on another

Comment: Maybe the problem is "One of them is in one view and the other on another"? Show me the html code

Comment: Added html code of both views

Comment: I guess the problem is that I'm using handlebars, and it only reads the JS script once, so the second view that i render won't pop up the modal because the script was already read. Any suggestions to overcome this?